# Edit a specific row in an asp repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater and on dataItembound i have something like this

```
((HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("prodName")).Visible = false;
```

This however sets all tablerows in the repeater to be invisible. I would like a specific one to be hidden. Is there a way to do this?

Heres the full imp

```
 protected void RepeaterCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        //Get category id
        string catId = Request.QueryString["stctid"];
        //Call function to check stock levels in the next loaded category
        bool stock = checkCategoryStockLevels(catId);

        if(stock == true)
        {
            ((HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("catName")).Visible = false;
            ((HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("catImg")).Visible = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: please show full implementation of your OnDataItemBound event...

Comment: I got it.

        for (int repeaterCount = 0; count < repeaterID.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            Label label = (Label)repeaterID.Items[repeaterCount].FindControl("labelID");
            label.Text = "Text";
        }

Thanks to all that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
    for (int repeaterCount = 0; count < repeaterID.Items.Count; count++)
    {
        Label label = (Label)repeaterID.Items[repeaterCount].FindControl("labelID");
        label.Text = "Text";
    }
```

Thanks to all that helped

Answer (score 0):

In the description you are retrieving the category identifier from the query string of the pages URL. This request will return the same value for all Repeater items and as such every "catName" and "catImg" HtmlTableRow will be hidden.

I assume you wish to hide the rows based on some value stored in the DataSource being bound to the repeater.

To do so you will need to access the DataItem in the ItemDataBound event and perform a check to determine which item requires the row to be hidden.

Below I have bound a List of strings to the Repeater, so I can access each item and perform a check like so, hiding only the HtmlTableRow in the ItemTemplate where the value of the DataItem equals "Item 1":

```
string dataItem = (string)e.Item.DataItem;
if (dataItem == "Item 1")
{
    ((HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("prodName")).Visible = false;   
}
```

I assume you are binding something more complex such as a DataRow or some other Object. Either way the process is the same, cast the DataItem and perform your check.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a ListView or a DataList instead, because then you can use data keys to determine row visibility based on a certain value.